# Get E-Mails from last 24Hours using Microsoft Graph API

Tags: outlook, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to get the emails I received within the last 24 hours using the Microsoft graph API.
Currently I'm using this request url: https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/messages

I currently get the last 10 emails. How do I have to modify the request url in order to get the Emails received within the last 24hours?

Answer (score 3):

Two ways you could do it first is with a Filter for messages with a received date greater than your search range eg

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/messages?Top=500&$filter=(receivedDateTime gt 2020-08-05T00:00:00Z)&Select=Subject,receivedDateTime
```

Or do a search using the re-severed keywords (today,yesterday etc)

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/messages?search="received:yesterday"&Select=Subject,receivedDateTime&Top=250
```

Comment: If we have a reference for all reserved keywords, could you please share @Glen?

Comment: they should be with the KQL doco https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/keyword-query-language-kql-syntax-reference